# How can I parse a stringified array of arrays (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string which represents an array. The items in the array can be characters, or arrays. So a string might look like: [a,b,[[],[d]],[],[[[]]],[[c,[t,s]],b]]

And I want to parse that out so it's a proper array with subarrays etc

So `"[a,b,[c,[d,e],[]]]"` would become:

```
[ 'a',
  'b',
  [ 'c',
    ['d','e'],
    []
  ]
]
```

Is there an easy way to do this in JavaScript?  Eg some kind of array equivalent of `JSON.parse`?  I tried `JSON.parse` but it throws an error (not unexpectedly).

Comment: What would `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` be?

Comment: If your string's value is "[a,b,[c,[d,e],[]]]", then JSON.parse should work.

Comment: @Emilien no, it won't. `a` is not a valid thing in JSON. Same with the other letters.

Comment: The key issue is that those characters aren't strings. If they were it would make for valid JSON and the parse would work.

Comment: @VLAZ sorry I assumed they were just placeholders for real values (strings or numbers). If that's REALLY what your string is like, you're absolutely right, that won't work.

Comment: *"so it's a proper array with subarrays"* - It's not clear to me what you mean by that.  Are you just trying to add whitespace to your output (new lines, indentation) for a human-readable display of this string?  Or is this supposed to be actual data that you're using in some way?

Comment: If you can't adjust your source, then something like this might help https://ryanmarcus.github.io/dirty-json/

Comment: Then the question is: what do you want ```a```,```b```,```c```, etc... to be in your output array ? If you want them to become string, then maybe try some kind of regExp on your input string to add some quotes around those characters so that JSON.parse works adequately.

Comment: Sorry, a,b,c etc are just strings in the final array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to process it to convert it into a format that JSON.parse would be able to handle. Your test case is simple so it is possible with an easy regular expression.

```js
const str = "[a,b,[c,[d,e],[]]]";
const obj = JSON.parse(str.replace(/([a-z]+)/gi,'"$1"'));
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Wow! This is an awesome solution!  In case the data was more complex, could an exclusion `RE`, such as `/([^\[\]\{\},]+)/gi`, be used?